# symfony2 override generated entity class

Tags: php, oop, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use YAML mapping and "doctrine:generate:entities AcmeDemoBunde" to generate setters & getters.

During development it happens that the mapping changes a bit and hence I have to regenerate setters & getters. However I wrote code in those setters & getters.

How would it be possible to use the default generated setters & getters file + another file where I could put all my custom methods and __construct which would override the default setters & getters file.

Comment: Do not use generators. Just make necessary changes yourself.

Comment: It saddens me but in the end I found no other way than yours. Magic Setters & Getters are said not to be the best practice :'(